# MySQL Count of a count where something occurs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Our system tracks reviews from users and we're looking to do a interface where we can get all the users in a room and the number of reviews they've done.

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.email, 
COUNT(b.review_id) as num_reviews
FROM users a LEFT JOIN reviews b ON a.user_id = b.created_by 
WHERE a.dataroom_id =  44 GROUP BY a.user_id ORDER BY num_reviews DESC
```

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.email, 
COUNT(b.review_id) as num_reviews, 
**COUNT(b.date_completed IS NOT NULL) AS completed** 
FROM users a LEFT JOIN reviews b ON a.user_id = b.created_by 
WHERE a.dataroom_id =  44 GROUP BY a.user_id ORDER BY num_reviews DESC
```

Where we count the number that that user has completed at the same time. That statement above gives everyone who has zero 1 and the rest the same number as they have total reviews.

A desired outcome would be a table like this:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ User_id ║ Email       ║ # Reviews ║ # Completed ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║    1    ║ test0@e.com ║     4     ║      2      ║
║    2    ║ test1@e.com ║     1     ║      0      ║
║    3    ║ test2@e.com ║     10    ║      5      ║
║    4    ║ test3@e.com ║     5     ║      3      ║
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `count()`, you want `sum()`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, 
       COUNT(r.review_id) as num_reviews, 
       SUM(r.risk_score IS NOT NULL) AS completed 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     reviews r
     ON u.user_id = r.created_by 
WHERE u.dataroom_id = 44
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY num_reviews DESC;
```

I fixed the table aliases so they are abbreviations for the table names, rather than arbitrary aliases.

Oh . . . what is happening?  `count(<expression>)` simply counts the number of times the expression is not `NULL`.  `sum(<expression>)` adds up the values.  MySQL (unlike other databases) treats "true" as 1 and "false" as 0.  So, the `sum()` adds up the number of times the boolean is true.

Alternatively, you can just use `count()` without the expression:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, 
       COUNT(r.review_id) as num_reviews, 
       COUNT(r.risk_score) AS completed
```

Comment: You're a wizard. It's always something as simple as this. Cheers Gordon!